# Using one variable to look up info in two tables

Tags: php, mysql

The code below works nicely.  Each "title" in the MySQL table "submission" is printed in reverse chronological order alongside its corresponding "loginid."

I have another MySQL table ("login") with the fields "loginid" and "username."  So each row has a "loginid" and a "username."  The "loginid" in these two MySQL tables "submission" and "login" are equivalent to each other.

In the HTML table printed below, how could I replace the "loginid" with the "username"?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
  <?php
    $sqlStr = "SELECT loginid, title, url, displayurl
          FROM submission ORDER BY datesubmitted DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysql_query($sqlStr);

    $arr = array(); 
    echo "<table class=\"samplesrec\">";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="sitename1"><a href="http://www.'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["title"].'</a></td>';
     echo '</tr>';
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td class="sitename2"><a href="http://www.'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["loginid"].'</a></td>';
     echo '</tr>';
     }
    echo "</table>"; 


    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a JOIN in your query, like so:

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT s.loginid, s.title, s.url, s.displayurl, l.username
             FROM submission AS s,
                  login AS l
            WHERE s.loginid = l.loginid
         ORDER BY s.datesubmitted DESC
            LIMIT 10";
```

Then just use the `$row['username']` field within your code.

bye